# BLPOP and MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots

Tags: redis

we use Redis in an ELK stack for buffering messages between our systems
and Elasticsearch. The messages are pushed into redis by a custom log4j-appender and popped by logstash.

Now there comes the problem: if the redis queue is running full (because e.g Elasticsearch is not running) redis switches to a mode were no persistent changes are allowed anymore. This makes sense, but popping messages from Redis (because e.g. ES is up again) would reduce the size of the queue in redis.

Is there an option to configure redis to allow blpop if the queue is full?

Best regards
Benjamin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From redis.conf:

> By default Redis will stop accepting writes if RDB snapshots are enabled
>   (at least one save point) and the latest background save failed.
>   This will make the user aware (in a hard way) that data is not persisting
>   on disk properly, otherwise chances are that no one will notice and some
>   disaster will happen.

In your case you should disable this option:

```
config set stop-writes-on-bgsave-error no
```

Do not forgot to restart redis after change this option.

Comment: this option kind of works, but is not very robust. If there are still messages pushed into redis without being poped (which is the case) redis will crash later on.

I think the problem is that Redis classifies the BLPOP-Operation as mutating (which it is, of course) and blocks it exactly like the RPUSH operation if the queue/redis is full. That is not a good behaviour for a message queue. It should only block pushing additional data if the queue is full.

Another idea?

Comment: You have no other options with that in Redis. Take care to ensure that you had a place on the disk to save RDB snapshot. Try to forse save manualy if got MISCONF. Or use stop-writes-on-bgsave-error and hope that the next time Redis try to save RDB it would be success.